# 2.8 evee - can I "mask" a mesh/material outside of a container (like a domain)?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, masking

Is there a way to easily define a volume where an object is visible, and hide it elsewhere ?
Thanks.

Comment: If the object intersects the volume partially, should it be (A) partially visible (B) transparent or (C) invisible and only appear once its origin enters the volume?

Comment: C would be nice, I guess A is more complicated...

Comment: A is just an intersect boolean modifier.

Answer (score 1):

This sound like a boolean modifier could help you.

[image: cube is animated to pass through volume mesh]
<sup>Simplified setup, with a cube and a VolumeMesh.</sup>

1. Add a **boolean modifier** to the object which needs to be invisible outside of the volume. Choose the *Intersect* operation (default) and choose the *VolumeMesh* as the object of the modifier.
   [image: boolean modifier settings]

[image: cube only shows up in the volume mesh]

Comment: won't make the meshes flickers or something, if there are modifiers on the object ?